# It is possible to use satellite map on OpenScales?

Tags: flex, openscales

It is possible to use satellite map on openscales, like that http://api.ign.fr/geoportail/api/doc/examples/geoportalFxMap_minimum.html
I'v seen a exemple :

```
<os:WMSC name="Nasa"  
             url="http://openscales.org/geoserver/gwc/service/wms"
             layers="bluemarble"
             format="image/jpeg"
             maxExtent="-180,-90,180,90"/>
```

But it's show just an image of earth and when i zoom in, image lose quality !?
Is there any other solution !?